# Perl print match and no match strings from file1 match in file2 match with million records

Tags: perl

This is what is required:

```
          File1    
      rama 
       krishna 
      mahadev 
        bentick 
      william
```

with million records

```
           File2 
        
             hello how are you
             rama is king of ayadhya 
             krishna is king of    dwarka 
             mahadev is great lord
             this is what is you go
```

with million records

Output required
*****strings matched-below****
rama is king of ayadhya
krishna is king of dwarka
mahadev is great lord

```
                ***strings unmatched-below ***** 
                -----------------------------  
              bentick  
               william  
                and so on
```

I tried this but did not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
if (scalar(@ARGV) != 2) {
  printf STDERR "Usage: fgrep.pl smallfile bigfile\n";
  exit(2);
}

my ($small_file, $big_file) = ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]);
my ($small_fp, $big_fp, %small_hash, $field);

open($small_fp, "<", $small_file) || die "Can't open $small_file: " . $!;
open($big_fp, "<", $big_file)     || die "Can't open $big_file: "   . $!;

# store contents of small file in a hash
while (<$small_fp>) {
  chomp;
  $small_hash{$_} = undef;
}
close($small_fp);

# loop through big file and find matches
while (<$big_fp>) {
  # no need for chomp
  $field = (split(/ /, $_))[1];
  if (defined($field) && exists($small_hash{$field})) {
    printf("%s", $_);
  }
}

close($big_fp);
exit(0);
```

Comment: For efficient matching of one of a huge number of possible strings, I like [Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS).

Answer (score 2):

Correcting the small mistakes you made:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if (scalar(@ARGV) != 2) {
  printf STDERR "Usage: fgrep.pl smallfile bigfile\n";
  exit(2);
}

my ($small_file, $big_file) = ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]);
my ($small_fp, $big_fp, %small_hash, $field);

open($small_fp, "<", $small_file) || die "Can't open $small_file: " . $!;
open($big_fp, "<", $big_file)     || die "Can't open $big_file: "   . $!;

# store contents of small file in a hash
while (<$small_fp>) {
  s/\s+//g;
  next unless $_;
  $small_hash{$_} = undef;
}
close($small_fp);

# loop through big file and find matches
while (<$big_fp>) {
  # no need for chomp
  $field = (split(/ /, $_))[0];
  if (defined($field) && exists($small_hash{$field})) {
    printf("%s", $_);
    $small_hash{$field}++;
  }
}
close($big_fp);

print "\n ***unmatched Strings***\n";
foreach my $key (keys %small_hash) {
    print "$key\n"
        unless $small_hash{$key};
}

exit(0);
```

- you left whitespace in the names.
- the first word is `(split(/ /, $_))[0]` not `(split(/ /, $_))[1]`
- you forgot to save which words you found and print them out

Comment: Stephen in above code , i want to find nearby values I mean nearby match example in File1  name as - rama 
krishna 

 and i want to print as few strings match in File2 
example some lines are 
------------------------------
rama .thename.org 
       krishna.theditor.org.gov 
can you suggest a switch in the code that can print the same .

My thnx in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "nearby values", sorry :(

Comment: If you want to print each match only once, you can test whether ti has been printed if the value $small_hash{$field} is set to a value >=1, by adding `next if $small_hash{$field};` in the loop

Comment: Thnx George for the input . I mean any word matches for example ram matches to ram.ava.org.gov  , mahadev matches with mahadev.au.org.gov